# install dual boot ubuntu on seperate hard drives (CMS/Bios)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, windows

i have windows 10 on my first drive installed with `(CMS BIOS)`  and i am trying to install ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on a separate second drive

i found this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/843649) but it is on `UEFI` is it going to work if i used it ? 
cause my windows 10 is installed on `CMS`

> Note: my bios has the option to change between `CMS/UEFI`

i am really confused what to do help please!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/246409/dual-booting-in-csm-mode says you cannot do this. If they are applicable, you can try and follow some of the suggestions they provide?

Comment: With newer UEFI hardware better to have all systems installed in UEFI boot mode. Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode on gpt drives since 2012, but users could use BIOS/CSM. But only if installing on two drives can boot mode be different between Windows & Ubuntu. And then you can only dual boot from UEFI menu, not grub.  How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is how it installs. Shows both BIOS & UEFI screens:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI If you use BIOS for Ubuntu, some advantage to gpt, but then you need a bios_grub partition.